# Declare a common onClick attribute for all buttons in styles.xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, buttonclick

My layout involves a lot of Buttons with all attributes absolutely same except the `android:text="button_name"` attribute.

The theme for these buttons is defines as follows in styles.xml

```
<style name="Core.ButtonStyleSmall">
    <item name="android:layout_width">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">8sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">6sp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:onClick">takeToApplication</item>
</style>
```

What I want to achieve is a **common onClick statement** for all of these buttons and thus I have added it here but it doesn't seem to work.

In my java file it still prompts a warning saying `Method'takeToApplication(android.view.View)' is never used`.

What is the correct way to do this? Please help me regarding this.

Comment: You may get that anyway. Java does not know anything about layout XML, and so it will not know that your method will be called via reflection. That is merely a warning. The bigger question is: does the method get called when the user clicks on the button? `onClick` is an unusual attribute to put in a style resource, and while I suppose it should work, I would not be shocked if there are problems.

Comment: If you declare the `onClick` in the layout.xml file the warning disappears and hence I assumed it will not work. Nevertheless I will try running it.

Comment: Lint may know to check layout XML files for `onClick` attributes and suppress the warning automatically. But there may be other cases that it misses (e.g., you had the method name in a string resource).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one had a definite answer, I will go ahead and answer it myself:

**Any xml attribute can be declared in the styles.xml file** for all the views that need to share any common attributes. Thus, onClick works just fine when declared there.

It gives you a warning beforehand saying `Method 'name_of_method' is never used`, but that is just because the call to the resources files happen at runtime. So the warning can be safely ignored, it renders no problems.